# add rows in the List

Tags: qt, qabstractlistmodel

I have class called **List** to print a list

```
class List : public QAbstractListModel
{
Q_OBJECT
Q_ENUMS(Roles)
```

**public**:

```
enum Roles {
    address =  Qt::UserRole + 1,
    name
};

DeviceList(QObject *parent = 0);

void addrows(const Manager &client);

int rowCount(const QModelIndex & parent = QModelIndex()) const;
QVariant data(const QModelIndex & index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const;
```

**protected**:

```
QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const;
```

**private**:

```
  QList< Manager > m_client;
};
```

And another class **Manager** as

```
class Manager : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    Q_PROPERTY(List* List READ getList CONSTANT)
```

**public**:

```
 Manager(const QString &address, const QString &name);

    QString address() const;
    QString name() const;

    virtual  List* getList() = 0;
```

**private**:

```
 QString m_address;
    QString m_name;

};
```

Now i am trying to **addrows** in **manager.cpp** as

```
void List::addrows(const Manager &client)
{
    beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), rowCount(), rowCount());

    m_client << client; // **i am getting error here** 

    endInsertRows();
}
```

My intention is to implement **getlist**  in **manager.cpp** file

```
List*  Manager :: getList()
{
   List* list = new  List();

    list->addrows(Manager("street1","John"));
    list->addrows(Manager("street2:","Tim"));
    list->addrows(Manager("street3","Roberrt"));

    return list;
}
```

Comment: And what's the error?

Comment: remove `=0` from `virtual List* getList() = 0;` in manager.h

Comment: but compile error is at addrows fun where i have commented

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the operator << you have to override the operator = in the class Manager. Instead of doing that use List  and handle list elements as pointer.

Comment: I didn't get you , can you elaborate a bit , or come up with example code